# asp.net membership profile update

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm working with asp.net member profiles. I can create the profile and retrieve values, but I can't seem to set property values.
I am using the following code:

```
var profile = MemberProfile.GetUserProfile();
profile.fullName = tbFullName.Text;
profile.country = tbCountry.Text;
profile.city = tbCity.Text;
profile.streetAddress = tbStreeAddress.Text;
profile.phoneNumber = tbPhoneNumber.Text;
profile.Save();
```

And this is not updating the profile.
I also looked up several solutions in the internet, but nothing seems to work.
The profile class looks like this:

```
public class MemberProfile : ProfileBase
{
    public static MemberProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
    {
        return (MemberProfile)Create(username);
    }

    public static MemberProfile GetUserProfile()
    {
        return (MemberProfile)Create(System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().UserName);
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string AuthGuid
    {
        get
        {
            var o = base.GetPropertyValue("auth_guid");
            if (o == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return (string)o;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetPropertyValue("auth_guid", value);
        }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string fullName
    {
        get
        {
            var o = base.GetPropertyValue("fullName");
            if (o == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return (string)o;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetPropertyValue("fullName", value);
        }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string country
    {
        get
        {
            var o = base.GetPropertyValue("country");
            if (o == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return (string)o;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetPropertyValue("country", value);
        }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string city
    {
        get
        {
            var o = base.GetPropertyValue("city");
            if (o == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return (string)o;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetPropertyValue("city", value);
        }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string streetAddress
    {
        get
        {
            var o = base.GetPropertyValue("streetAddress");
            if (o == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return (string)o;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetPropertyValue("streetAddress", value);
        }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string phoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            var o = base.GetPropertyValue("phoneNumber");
            if (o == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return (string)o;
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetPropertyValue("phoneNumber", value);
        }
    }        
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a pre-built usercontrol someone else wrote on the Umbraco community site.

http://umbracoprofileeditor.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You also need to create the properties in the web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
        <providers>
          <clear />
          <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" />
          <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" />
        </providers>
        <properties>
          <add name="auth_guid" allowAnonymous ="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
          <add name="fullName" allowAnonymous ="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
          <add name="country" allowAnonymous ="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
          <add name="streetAddress" allowAnonymous ="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
          <add name="phoneNumber" allowAnonymous ="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
          <add name="city" allowAnonymous ="false" provider="UmbracoMemberProfileProvider" type="System.String" />
        </properties>
      </membership>
```